# How to omit dictionary source file in dictionary completion

Tags: autocompletion, dictionary, ins-completion

```
<C-X><C-K>
```

complete words with long dictionary file name, such as /home/xxx/.vim/mydict.
I'd like to omit or shorten the descriptive info.
I have googled but got no hints.
Any advice?

Comment: It can't be done. You can't just shorten the popup menu paths. I suggest you ignore that.